# Use a command line program from within Java

Tags: java, command-line

How can I use a command line program from within Java?

I'm trying to pass a graph definition in the dot-language (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language)) to the interpreter program dot (see [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org)) through java.

The problem is, that the program does not answer, after I have sent the dot-graph to its InputStream, because it does not know, that I'm finished sending the description.

This is, what I currently have:

```
package exercise4;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream out = System.out;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            final String start =
                "strict graph LSR%1$d {\n" +
                " node [shape=circle color=lightblue style=filled];\n\n" +
                " {rank=same; A--B [label=6];}\n" +
                " {rank=same; C--D [label=12]; D--E [label=4];}\n" +
                " A--C [label=4]; B--D [label=4]; B--E [label=9];\n\n" +
                " node [shape=record color=\"#000000FF\" fillcolor=\"#00000000\"];\n}\n";
            Process dot = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dot -Tsvg");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            out = new PrintStream(dot.getOutputStream(), false, "UTF-8");
            out.printf(start, 0);

            out.flush();
            out.close();

            while(in.ready()) {
                System.out.println(in.readLine());
            }
            in.close();
            dot.destroy();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't know you're finished? By what mechanism is it supposed to know you are?

Comment: 1- Use ProcessBuilder, it will make your life easier. 2- It's not recommended to use readLine when reading from processes, not all process will output line endings. Use Process#waitFor to get the processes exit code, which may help you diagnose the problem

Comment: Go through the Java World article linked from the [`exec` info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info), implement **all** the recommendations, then break the args into a `String` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the `Process`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you are reading from the wrong input stream.  Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4741987/1686330