# Play Java Framework return php file to view

Tags: java, php, playframework

```
return ok(views.html.index.render(Group.all(), groupForm));
```

I need a way for the framework to use index.scala.php file instead of the default index.scala.html file. The code above renders the html file but is there a way to use the php file instead. I want the play framework to use php files instead of html.

Comment: Use some PHP framework in that case

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea how this can be accomplished, but I imagine any hope of pulling off such a wild idea is to use the [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/). You would have to rewrite the Play template rendering engine to generate HTML from PHP files.

Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a simple bridge between CakePHP and Symfony 2 Controllers, so I can try to provide some general approach.  I can't provide specifics because I have never worked with Play personally, and you are bridging across different languages where I was not.

Definitely, take a look at the link @Vidya provided.  It might provide what you need already, but I've never worked with it personally.  Otherwise, I would avoid these [alternatives](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/FAQ.html) and build your own.

- Read a bit of theory on this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern
- Your View file will sent things off to your existing PHP infrastructure and then build your HTTP response depending on what comes back.  Build a system call using `java.lang.Runtime.exec(String)`.
- I'm guessing your PHP uses superglobals - If so, you might be able to get away with using a single generic passthrough view file.  You'll have to convert query string (https://serverfault.com/questions/187025/), request body + headers ([How to pass parameters from command line to $_POST in php-script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655284/)), and cookies ([Is it possible to read cookie/session value while executing PHP5 script through command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578595/)) from Play to PHP
- Set the response body + status code based on what comes back from the PHP output ([Redirect Runtime.getRuntime().exec() output with System.setOut();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741878)).  I don't know how to detect errors + warnings in your PHP script.

I am sorry I don't have more details, but I hope this gives you an idea of what's involved.