# How to print the output of a bash script to Java standard output

Tags: java, bash, shell, java.util.logging

I want to see the output of a bash script to be printed in my java standard output.

My shell script `script01.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "SQL version is:"
basename $(docker exec sql-container readlink current)
```

The output for above would be for example:

```
MyTerminal$> ./script01.sh
SQL version is:
14-2-release01
```

I want this to be shown in my java standard output.
When I run this method, it doesn't print!

```
private static void printCurrentVersion() throws IOException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"bash", "-c", "./script01.sh"});
    System.out.println("Did this # println appear?");
}
```

However only thing that prints is: `Did this # println appear?`

Any idea?

Comment: Did you search before asking this question? Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343066/reading-streams-from-java-runtime-exec?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: If you want to the script's stdout to go to your Java process's stdout without reading it through a pipe, you can use `ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT)` or `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a duplicate of [Redirect Runtime.getRuntime().exec() output with System.setOut();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741878/redirect-runtime-getruntime-exec-output-with-system-setout)

Comment: While I agree that this problem isn't universally unique, it is however trying to achieve something different to the one you suggested. Thanks for your input.