# Exit(1) when running exec on java

Tags: java, unix

I am running sed command in java program when i execute my java file in linux.
when i ran the command alone in linux, this will work -> `sed '1d;$d' /home/sample/testdata.txt > /home/output/testupdate.txt`

however when i ran my java program in linux, its returning exit(1) error . i have read through and use as an array but its still failing .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] cmd = {"sed", "sed '1d;$d' /home/sample/testdata.txt > /home/output/testupdate.txt"};
    String s;
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("line: " + s);
        }
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("exit: " + p.exitValue());
        p.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I have my doubts you can pass `>` as an argument and having it parsed as "output redirection". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741878/redirect-runtime-getruntime-exec-output-with-system-setout) for a better way.

Comment: '>' is shell syntax, and I don't think you're running a shell via 'exec'.

Comment: You don’t need `sed` at all.  Java can do everything `sed` can do.  And using Java means it can run on systems that don’t have `sed` installed (like Windows).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Runtime's exec() method is not redirecting the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238714/runtimes-exec-method-is-not-redirecting-the-output)

Comment: @Joe , this is able to launch execute from .sh file. but i am trying to execute within java itself without the need to create an additional .sh script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is not a shell so does not handle redirects - your original command only works via your Linux shell which understands ">".

You can make Java launch the shell to execute the command, say if you are using bash:

```
 String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash", "-c"
    , "sed '1d;$d' /home/sample/testdata.txt > /home/output/testupdate.txt"};
```

Alternatively see the other helpful comments which link to other pages on dealing with the redirects within the Java code, or to do it inside Java itself (such as with `Files.lines` / streams).

Comment: this work fine but i was wondering what does "-c" mean, tried googling but i could not find what is it for

Comment: The "-c" tells bash to run the given command, then exit. Without "-c" bash will assume the parameter is a script. Compare `bash ls` vs `bash -c ls`.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need `sed`.  Java can do everything `sed` can do.

In your case, it appears you are using `sed` to remove the first and last line from a file.  Here’s how you would do that in Java:

```
Path source = Path.of("/home/sample/testdata.txt");
Path destination = Path.of("/home/output/testupdate.txt");

long lineCount;
try (Stream<?> lines = Files.lines(source)) {
    lineCount = lines.count();
}

long lastLine = lineCount - 1;

try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(source);
     BufferedReader out = Files.newBufferedWriter(destination)) {

    // Skip first line
    String line = in.readLine();

    long counter = 0;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (++counter < lastLine) {
            out.write(line);
            out.newLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If for some reason you *absolutely need* to use an external process, there are many other questions and answers which cover your mistake:  `>` is not understood by `sed`.  Normally, it is the shell (like `bash`) which interprets file redirection.

The proper way to run your command would have been:

```
ProcessBuilder builder =
    new ProcessBuilder("sed", "1d;$d", "/home/sample/testdata.txt");

builder.redirectOutput(new File("/home/output/testupdate.txt"));
builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

Process p = builder.start();
```