# How to have input-redirection with Javas ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder, io-redirection

How can I apply input redirection to Javas ProcessBuilder?

E.g. use cat of Linux

```
cat x.txt > output.txt
```

My code

```
// read x.txt with cat and redirect the output to output.txt
public static void main (String args []) throws Exception
{
    List <String> params = new ArrayList <String> ();
    params.add ("cat");
    params.add ("x.txt");       
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder (params);
    pb.redirectOutput (new File ("output.txt"));
    Process p = pb.start ();
    p.waitFor (3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println ("exit="+p.exitValue());
}
```

That works fine!
But how to change from file to input-redirection?

```
cat << END > output
```

I tried this - but does not work.

```
public static void main (String args []) throws Exception
{
    List <String> params = new ArrayList <String> ();
    params.add ("cat");
    params.add ("/dev/stdin");
    params.add ("<<";
    params.add ("END");
    
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder (params);
    pb.redirectOutput (new File ("output.txt"));
    Process p = pb.start ();
    OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream ();
    os.write ("\nblabla\nEND\n".getBytes ());
    p.waitFor (3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println ("exit="+p.exitValue());
}
```

No matter what I tried it returned with 1 (instead of 0 for success) or did not finish.

Comment: `<< END` is shell syntax. The line `cat << END > output` would be followed by some text followed by a line `END` in a shell script or as input (`stdin`) for a shell. Where do you want the input to come from when running a process from your Java program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exit(1) when running exec on java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68083327/exit1-when-running-exec-on-java)

Answer (score 1):

The command `cat << END > output` is a shell command so you need to run it via shell as

```
 List <String> params = List.of("/bin/sh", "-c", "cat << END > output")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `os.close()` to let the process know that no more data is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by skipping the

```
<<END
```

but then opened an OutputStream after starting the process.
Over that I put the files content into the process.
Flushing and closing of the stream is important.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder (params);
Process p = pb.start ();
                
OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream ();
os.write (content_string);  
os.flush ();
os.close ();
```